# 2D Discrete Fourier Transform on an Image - Example with numbers (rgb)

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing

I am trying to write my own function that takes an image, an pixel by pixel it calculates that pixel value that will produce a 2D Fourier Transform image.

I have no idea about signal processing, my background is CS.

I have been reading this,

http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/

and this

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm

and I saw the Fourier equation. It seems that I am going to need a simple nested loop, to go through all the pixels, but I do not know how to apply the equation. From the first link, M and N are the width and height of the image right? x and y are x and y of course.

But how do I interpret this: f(x,y)(e^-j2....) ?

So it is the value of the pixel, (let's say rgb grayscaled, 249) multiplied by the rest which is (e^-j2....)? I know j is the imaginary part, but if you have a look, it mentions a U and V unknowns aswell, which I do not know what value to assign to them.

Thanks.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are the indices of your new image $F$ in frequency domain. So you know these, they run from 0 to N-1 and M-1 respectively.

Comment: so they basically take the same values of x and y ?

Comment: aaaaaok I got it, so for u=1, and v =1, I still need to go through the pixels of all the original image. ok. what about the e function ? do I need to replace it with the sin + cos to get the real part?

Comment: Yes, for each u and v you still need to go through all x and y all the time. You should just use the e function. If you want to implement a fast computation you should take a look at fast dft algorithms like Cooley Tukey for 1D fft first.

Comment: Ok cool, I am going to give it a try. It confuses a bit why it uses the indices u,v in the main function, I mean for u=1, v=1 for example it will not make any difference. Anyway. Thanks!

Comment: They will ;) u and v are in the e function as well

Comment: Hello, another question, you said I can use the function as it is, if I do that I cannot get the real part. I would need to break the exponential function into the cos and sin method. other I can't get a value for my pixel

Comment: You need a signal of even symmetry, otherwise you will always have imaginary parts. I don't know exactly what your goal is, but you might want to read the wiki article on the Discrete Cosine Transform. However, this is a bit more difficult and also its not the "complete" fft.

Comment: I am trying to input an image and output an image that is a DFT of the original. See here for an idea: http://www.nayuki.io/page/how-to-implement-the-discrete-fourier-transform. I kinda understood this link but again I do not get where he gets the Re(x) and Im(x) values from. If i want to get the magnitude only, then I will use euler's formula and ignore the i*sin(...) part right ?